# Simple assembly math

Tags: assembly, x86

Hello I'm trying to learn assembler x86.
I want to SUB word and byte.

I have

```
MOV al, a
MUL a
```

and

```
MOV ax, 3
MUL b
```

How i should sub those? Thanks.

Comment: The `MUL` is confusing stuff and has nothing to do with the question. Do you want to subtract word and byte, or word and dword (which are the result of the multiplication...) For the former, zero or sign extend to word and subtract. For the latter, use `SUB` and `SBB`.

Comment: subtract word and dword

Answer (score 0):

## Subtract word from byte

### The result is a word

Extend the byte and do a word-word subtraction.

**Zero-extension (for unsigned subtrahend)**

```
;AX = minuend WORD, BL = subtrahend BYTE

movzx bx, bl            ;BX = 16-bit zero extension of BL
sub ax, bx              ;AX = 16-bit result
```

or

```
;AX = minuend WORD, BL = subtrahend BYTE

xor bh, bh              ;BX = 16-bit zero extension of BL
sub ax, bx              ;AX = 16-bit result
```

**Sign-extension (for signed subtrahend)**

```
;AX = minuend WORD, BL = subtrahend BYTE

movsx bx, bl            ;BX = 16-bit sign extension of BL
sub ax, bx              ;AX = 16-bit result
```

or

```
;AX = minuend WORD, BL = subtrahend BYTE

mov bh, bl
sar bh, 7               ;BX = 16-bit zero extension of BL
sub ax, bx              ;AX = 16-bit result
```

or

```
;BX = minuend WORD, AL = subtrahend byte
;Note BX and AX swapped role

cbw                     ;AX = 16-bit sign extension of AL              
sub bx, ax              ;BX = 16-bit result
```

### The result is a byte

If the subtrahend word value fits a byte ([0-255] for unsigned, [-128, 127] for signed) then shrink the word into a byte and do a byte-byte subtraction.

**Shrinking**

```
;AL = minuend BYTE, BX = subtrahend WORD
                   ;Ignore high (zero) byte of subtrahend
sub al, bl         ;AL = 8-bit result
```

If the subtrahend word value *doesn't* fits a byte ([0-255] for unsigned, [-128, 127] for signed) then scale the word into a byte and do a byte-byte subtraction.

**Scaling**

```
;AL = minuend BYTE, BX = subtrahend WORD
                     ;Scale WORD by using the high byte
sub al, bh           ;AL = 8-bit result
```

---

## Subtract byte from word

The results above all holds with minuend and subtrahend swapped.

---

## Subtract word from dword

We assume that no 32-bit registers are available.

### The result is a dword

Split the subtraction into two (high and low) parts and use the CF from the low part.
In decimal, 1234 - 99 = 1135 can be split as 24-99 and 12-00 (with the borrow from the other subtraction)

<sub>1</sub> <sub>12</sub> <sub>1</sub>
     <s>3</s> 4
     9 9
     ----
     3 5

<sub>1</sub>
     1 2
     0 0
     ----
     1 1

In assembly a subtraction with borrow is achieved through `sbb`

**Zero extended split subtraction (for unsigned subtrahend)**

```
;DX:AX = minued DWORD, BX = subtrahend WORD

sub ax, bx           ;Low part
sbb dx, 0            ;High part
```

**Sign extended split subtraction (for signed subtrahend)**

```
;DX:AX = minued DWORD, BX = subtrahend WORD

mov cx, bx
sar cx, 15           ;CX = Sign extension of BX
sub ax, bx           ;Low part
sbb dx, cx           ;High part
```

or

```
;CX:BX = minued DWORD, AX  = subtrahend WORD
;NOTE that the input registers are different

cwd                  ;Sign extend AX into DWORD DX:AX
sub bx, ax           ;Low part
sbb cx, dx           ;High part
```

### The result is a word

The results for the word-byte case can all be trivially converted for the dword-word case.

---

## Subtract dword from word

The results above all holds with minuend and subtrahend swapped.